# Can not convert Base64 String to UIImage on IOS Swift3

Tags: image, swift3, base64, decode, encode

I have a string file that contains base64string of image. I'm sure that base64String is correct, because i used the website for checking: 
https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter
with file data: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/10zjyzgcyv7s08m/data_base.txt?dl=1
(download and copy the content to the above website to generate the image )

But, On IOS Device , i can't convert it to image . This is my code (Swift3) :

```
    if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data_base", ofType: "txt") {
    do {
      let text3 = try String(contentsOfFile: filepath, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
      let dataDecoded : Data = Data(base64Encoded: text3, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
      let decodedimage = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
      self.imageView.image = decodedimage

    } catch {

    }
  }else {
    print("file is not exist")
  }
```

Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Please be more specific of what is not working. Is the String read successfully from the file? Is `dataDecoded` initialized successfully? Is `UIImage` non-nil?

Comment: Useless `try catch` ^^.
Can you provide error message?

Comment: attached file `data_base.txt` is wrong. You can check on any site resource base64<->image

Comment: decodedimange is always nil.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes, reading is successed. dataDecoded has value, but UIImage is nil

Comment: @IgorKotkovets. data_base.txt is correct. I tried decode to Image successfully. You can check at site : https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter